# Re-apply formulas to a new source of same type in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am working on building reports in `Power BI`. I have created various reports using formulas etc. Now I am going to add another source of data that has the same number of columns as my previous source.

**Source Data**
[image]

**Source 2**

[image]

I have added some formulizations and new columns that I want exactly to replicate onto the new source which has the same column names, type but different data.

Is there any way that I can do this? Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: The cleanest way is to load both sources into the same table and add a column called "Source type" or something, then you'd have no repetition of formulas/calculated columns/etc.

Comment: do you mean transformation in M/PowerQuery or in DAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want two connections in one query.
For this purpose you define a parameter.(For example "Connection")
If its value was 1, the query loaded from source 1 and if its value was 2 was loaded from source 2.

````
let  
    MySource = if Connection=1 then
        let
            Source = source_1,
            #"Changed Type" = ...,
        in
            #"Changed Type"
    else
        let
            Source = source_2,
            #"Changed Type" = ...,        
        in
            #"Changed Type",
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(MySource, {"Column3"})
    #"Removed Columns1" = ...
in
    #"Removed Columns1"```
````

Comment: To be precise I want both sources to use the same formulas and calculations. One way to do it is to do it manually but I want to do some automation. i.e. I have a single `pbix` file and I want to have 2 sources of the same data type and the same number of columns. `Source 1` has some calculations and formulizations so, as `Source 2` has the same data types and  columns but different data, I want to apply the calculations  and formulizations automatically to my source 2

Comment: Did you want to transfer Source 1 table formulas to Source 2 table?

Comment: Yes exactly this is what i want

Comment: You can use **Tabular Editor** for this. In it, you can easily copy and paste all formulas from tables to each other.

[https://github.com/TabularEditor/TabularEditor/releases](https://github.com/TabularEditor/TabularEditor/releases)

Comment: It's for power BI ?

Comment: Yes, An External Tool that is used in Power BI like Dax Studio.

Comment: so I have to download and install it inside the power bi ?

Comment: Download and Install the Tabular Editor on your system. If PowerBIDesktop is up-to-date a tab with name **External Tools** is added to it automatically.

Comment: How can I reapply the formulas ?